# unable to run c++ in visual studio code on m1 chipset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

I have wrote a very simple program in c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

but its showing error in

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

please help me with this

Comment: Can you provide the command you used for compiling?

Comment: Make sure to save the file before compiling.

Comment: @kiner_shah I have not installed some packages required to run c++, and  what bop suggested I have done now its running fine